# Proper way to save and load RadioGroup

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have a RadioGroup with 2 RadioButtons, Male and Female. I store their values like this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(preferences, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            rButton=(RadioButton) findViewById(rGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            editor.putString("gender",rButton.getText()+"");
```

and load them like this

```
SharedPreferences editor = getSharedPreferences(preferences, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String toast=editor.getString("gender","Male")+"";
    if (toast.equals("Female")){rGroup.check(R.id.radioButton2);}
    else{rGroup.check(R.id.radioButton);}
```

This works, however, it seems like a weird way to save and store them. Is there a better way to do that?
[Android store radiogroup id in sharedpreferences and load it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693817/android-store-radiogroup-id-in-sharedpreferences-and-load-it#comment71109884_19694314)
Can a view change its id number after changing the code or something else?

Comment: What's weird about it? You can store male/female, true/false, 0/1 or anyway you like. It's your call.

Comment: in this case, there are only 2 options. If there were more, the if-else statement would become longer. I was wondering if there was a more effective option, like for example rGroup.check("Male"), which would find the button with the male text and check it

Comment: If there were more then a when statement would be the solution.